# Can I use a function in PHP's array_search or sort function?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com APIs, though I wouldnt say this is a Parse question.

I have an array of ParseObjects called `$groups` and an array of ParseObjects called `$inputs`.

I already have both of these, so I do not want make any new queries.

All of the input objects are children of one of the group objects. I'd like to get an array of all of the `$inputs` that belong to each `$group`.

One way I could do this would be:

```
$groups= // array of ParseObjects
$inputs= // array of ParseObjects

foreach ($groups as $group) 
{
    $inputsInGroup=array();
    foreach ($inputs as $input) 
    {
        if($input->get('parent')==$group)
        {
                array_push($inputsInGroup,$input);
        }
     }
    //here I can use $inputsInGroup which will contain all elements that have this group as their parent
}
```

That would work, but seams really inefficient as it has to search the whole list of inputs for each group, including any that it already determined belonged to a previous group.

**Is there a way to supply a function to `array_search ()` or `sort()` to return objects in the array that pass this check `$input->get('parent')==$group`?**

I know you can do this with jQuery's `sort()` seems like PHP likely has a similar method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had an unneeded nested loop there - that's why

```
$groups; // array of ParseObjects
$inputs; // array of ParseObjects

$ibg; // inputs by group

foreach($inputs as $input) {
    var $group = $input->get('parent')->getObjectId();
    if(!isset($ibg[$group])){
        $ibg[$group] = array();
    }
    $ibg[$group][] = $input;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work in this case as `$group` is an object and "Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type."

Comment: Use whatever key of the object identifies it as the key instead then ( $input->get('parent')->id or whatever )

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is to apply a filter, with a custom **callback**, to an array, which can be done with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter). However, the change is only paradigmatic in nature — in that the asymptotic complexity won't change much.

```
array_filter($groups, function ($group) use ($inputs) {
    foreach($inputs as $input) {
        if ($input->get('parent') == $group) {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Both are still `O(n * k)` in time complexity, but one uses a more functional, as opposed to procedural, approach.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, I was hoping php had a built in function that was more optimized to this sort of thing.

Comment: The problem isn't with PHP. The operation you're conducting has a poorly chosen data structure for it to be optimal. Searching a hashmap (which is what an array/object is in PHP), is only `O(1)` if what you're searching for is the hash (i.e. `$array['key']`). Here you're searching for a value inside of the map, making it a linear search. What's worse is you want to search against an adjacency list, making it an even more extrapolated linear search. It seems someone more familiar with this *Parse.com API* has offered up a more efficient solution utilizing the API itself.